# Speed Up Simple Multidimensional Counter Code

Tags: python, performance, numpy, optimization, indexing

This is the slow code:

```
def doCounts(maskA1, maskA2, maskA3, counts, maskB):
    counts[0, maskB & maskA1] += 1
    counts[1, maskB & maskA2] += 1
    counts[2, maskB & maskA3] += 1
```

Is there a way to do this in one pass / make it faster?

Answer (score 1):

Vectorisation is likely difficult or not possible. The hint here is that advanced indexing in the second dimension, e.g. `maskB & maskA1`, can have arbitrary `True` values for each row. So you can't isolate an `m x n` array for indexing.

A naïve `for` loop using [`numba`](http://numba.pydata.org/) seems to improve performance by a factor:

```
# Python 3.6.5, NumPy 1.14.3, Numba 0.38.0

import numpy as np
from numba import njit

@njit
def doCounts(maskA1, maskA2, maskA3, counts, maskB):
    mask1, mask2, mask3 = maskB & maskA1, maskB & maskA2, maskB & maskA3
    for i in range(counts.shape[0]):
        m1, m2, m3 = mask1[i], mask2[i], mask3[i]
        for j in range(counts.shape[1]):
            if m1:
                counts[0, j] += 1
            if m2:
                counts[1, j] += 1
            if m3:
                counts[2, j] += 1
    return counts

def doCounts_original(maskA1, maskA2, maskA3, counts, maskB):
    counts[0, maskB & maskA1] += 1
    counts[1, maskB & maskA2] += 1
    counts[2, maskB & maskA3] += 1
    return counts

n = 100
np.random.seed(0)
m1, m2, m3, mB = (np.random.randint(0, 2, n**3).astype(bool) for _ in range(4))
counts = np.random.randint(0, 100, (3, n**3))

assert np.array_equal(doCounts(m1, m2, m3, counts, mB),
                      doCounts_original(m1, m2, m3, counts, mB))

%timeit doCounts(m1, m2, m3, counts, mB)           # 5.36 ms
%timeit doCounts_original(m1, m2, m3, counts, mB)  # 40.2 ms
```

Comment: @unutbu, Yep, nice! That does indeed bring the time back down to ~5ms.